# Outputing an database result in reverse

Tags: php

Here is an situation that probably has an easy solution but I just can't figure it out...

I have a analytics dashboard that shows the metrics in a line chart based on year, quarter (1-4)

I need to grab the last 8 newest records in a database..simple, order by year,quarter limit 0,8. BUT I need to display it left to right with the oldest year, first quarter.. So actually in reverse, not newest to oldest. So I need something like:

```
2011 - Quarter 2
2011 - Quarter 3
2011 - Quarter 4
2012 - Quarter 1
2012 - Quarter 2
2012 - Quarter 3
2012 - Quarter 4
2013 - Quarter 1 (Which is the last added record)
```

I was just going to query it based on the year DESC, quarter ASC then just reverse the output. Was going to use a for loop and set the `$i` to `8`, `$i > 0`, `$i--` then just increment from last record to first. Problem is I have no idea how to get the row number.

So in short, I need to query newest to oldest, but output oldest to newest. So, this is not an SQL Query question, an output question using mysql.

Comment: No idea I was supposed to do that and I dont see where that is at.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Revenue WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT id FROM Revenue WHERE ... youc criteria ... ORDER BY ... criteria order ...) 
  ORDER BY ... display order ...
```

Comment: Here is the answer:
$results = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = array_reverse(mysql_fetch_array($results))) {

echo $row['something'];

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
$results = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($row = array_reverse(mysql_fetch_array($results))) { 

echo $row['something']; 

}
```